# How to do subtraction between two fields in a Table using an SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to display the subtraction of two values from two different columns to a third column using a SQL query.

This is the table structure:

```
------------------------------------
id | subject | Time1 | Time2| Time3
------------------------------------
1  | String1 | 50    |  78  | 
2  | String2 | 60    |  99  |  
3  |         |       |      |
```

I want to subtract Time2 from Time1 if both Time1 and Time2 has data and store in Time3.

Output should be like as

```
------------------------------------
id | subject | Time1 | Time2| Time3
------------------------------------
1  | String1 | 50    |  78  |  28
2  | String2 | 60    |  99  |  39
3  |         |       |      |
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT *, `Time2`-`Time1` AS `Time3` FROM `tablename`
```

Answer (score 2):

```
`SELECT 
     id, 
     subject, 
     Time1, 
     Time2, 
     IF( Time1 != '' AND Time2 != '', Time2-Time1, '') as Time3 
FROM tbl_time`
```

Comment: could you please edit to format the code? highlight all the code and press Ctrl+K

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    id
    ,subject
    ,Time1
    ,Time2
    ,Time2-Time1 as Time3
FROM tbl
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Time1` and `Time2` are Number columns, you can use a simple subtraction:

```
select id, subject, Time1, Time3, Time2 - Time1 as Time3 from myTable
```

Comment: @kris Then my asnwer should work. Give a try. If my answer helped, accepting it as correct would be appreciated.

Comment: sure I haven't checked the solution yet; Will check and update. I don't want to do the calculation if any of the Time1/2 field is empty.

Answer (score 1):

just try this

```
select id, subject, Time1, Time2, Time2-Time1 as Time3  from mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

This checks the existence of data in `Time1` and `Time2`: if there is enough data, `Time3 = Time2 - Time1`; otherwise it's `null`

```
select id, subject, Time1, Time2, 
   ifnull(Time1, null, ifnull(Time2, null, Time2 - Time1)) as Time3 
from myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

If Time1 and Time2 are datetime fields, then you should use `TIMEDIFF` function in MySQL to be able to correctly format the Time3 field.

```
SELECT id, subject, Time1, Time2, TIMEDIFF(Time1, Time2) as Time3 
  FROM tbl
```

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-timediff-function.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT id, subject, Time1, Time2, CONCAT(Time2 - Time1) AS Time3 FROM tabel
```