# How to calculate in PL/SQL Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 columns, each columns have 2 rows. For example

```
A     B
100   200
200   300
```

So that I would like to calculate like this

```
Total A          Total B

200-100 = 100   300-200=100
```

Show

```
Total A     Total B
100         100
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44366341/how-to-do-subtraction-between-two-fields-in-a-table-using-an-sql-query

Comment: I think you need to provide more context, I can't think of a real world problem something like this.

Comment: What if there are three rows?

Answer (score 1):

Using `MAX()` and `MIN()` aggregate functions:

```
SELECT MAX(A) - MIN(A) AS "Total A",
       MAX(B) - MIN(B) AS "Total B"
FROM TableName
```

Comment: if seconds is less than first row? what's happen

Comment: It won't depend on the row order, it simply the maxvalue - minvalue. Please check the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cd112cd2a941a88a9e23e5be4a714875)

Comment: But I always use seconds row before first row every times

Comment: Then you need to use [Barbaros Özhan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56573927)'s answer. Working [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b131910a9cb1d1c5302a0ba22636edc6)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you exactly want to manage. If the problem is related to the difference between consecutive rows, using `lead()` or `lag()` window analytic functions might be a smart way :

```
with t( a, b ) as
(
 select 100, 200 from dual union all 
 select 200, 300 from dual 
), t2 as
(
select lead(a) over (order by 1) - a as "Total A",
       lead(b) over (order by 1) - b as "Total B",
       row_number() over (order by 1) as rn
  from t        
)
select *
  from t2
 where rn = 1;

Total A  Total B    RN
100      100        1
```

Comment: @ChawinthapongAiemmongkolsakul you're welcome. Please consider accepting one of the answers which you think most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can query it like this,

```
WITH your_table AS 
   (SELECT 100 a, 200 b
      FROM DUAL
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 200 a, 300 b
      FROM DUAL
     ORDER BY 1 DESC)
SELECT SUM(DECODE(ROWNUM, 1, a, -1*a)) TOTAL_A, SUM(DECODE(ROWNUM, 1, b, -1*b)) TOTAL_B
  FROM your_table;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this as below

```
Select * , `entity1`-`entity2` As `entity3` 
FROM tbl
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Bro their is two understanding in your question first you want to delete from max value and which solution provided to you by someone else and other is you want to delete from last row/second row. So the solution is provided to you for second approach. please discuss if any query.

```
select sum(Result.A) as A, sum(Result.B) as B, from (
    select top 1 A , B from Table_name order by id_row_order desc
    union all
    select top 1 - A , -B from Table_name order by id_row_order Asc
) as Result
```

Comment: Oracle does not support the `TOP` syntax.

Comment: I think so *-*z